# Creating a windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows, taskbar

in previous versions of windows you could create a taskbar that was actually a html page...    Is there any way, in windows 10, to put any custom content on the task bar - essentially I want to write a program that puts a completely custom display there with both active and passive content.

If not, is it possible to do something like a taskbar - ie put something on the screen that actually reduces the desktop size - so it's always on top and stuff that is maximized doesn't overwrite that space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case anyone is wondering - the magic word is "Appbar" - I found an article saying how to build an appbar in C# that gave me everything I needed.