# How to create Windows 11 taskbar application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, taskbar, windows-11

I want to create a Windows 11 application that will work as built-in apps like "Widgets" or "Chat" in taskbar using C#. There is very little information on this subject on the Internet, so I want to ask those who understand the Windows 11 ecosystem. Where can I get documentation or API for developing my own taskbar application?

I also found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234626/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-windows-10-app-that-reside-in-taskbar-similar-to-peop), but this thing is for Windows 10, in which I'm not interested in. But this is the same thing of what I'm trying to achieve.

Sorry for my English and thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a .NET Windows Forms application that only runs in the System Tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/how-can-i-make-a-net-windows-forms-application-that-only-runs-in-the-system-tra)

Comment: @OrhanErday I will consider this as a last resort, if I do not figure out how to do it in the format of the "Start" button, "Widgets" or "Chat". Microsoft did it somehow and I want to do this thing too. But thanks anyway, it's already better than nothing at all.

Comment: IDeskBand? Not sure if they are supported in 11...

Comment: @KhoDis did you found a way to do this?